# Why do many market observers suggest that Bitcoin production costs can serve as the lower bound of Bitcoin’s price range in a bear market?

Tags: exchange-rate, market

I read on https://decrypt.co/105251/how-much-does-cost-mine-1-bitcoin:

> Many market observers suggest that production costs also can serve “as the lower bound of Bitcoin’s price range in a bear market.

Why do many market observers suggest that Bitcoin production costs can serve as the lower bound of Bitcoin’s price range in a bear market?

Comment: A Bitcoin production costs depend on the block era and on how much miner competition.

Comment: Thanks Mercedes, good point.